# не увеличивается точность нейросети на тестовом наборе

Tags: python, keras

точность на тренировочном наборе нормально увеличивается, а вот на тестовом никак, использовал dropout и l2 регуляризацию - не помогло. Также менял количество слоев и нейронов в каждом, не помогает. даных для обучения больше достать не получается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

набор даных можно скачать по ссылке: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WrfFHJ7SfS-d9eRuiVvq_gSDSVNgcO1p/view?usp=sharing

ниже одна из многих вариаций которую я пробовал(максимально сократил, но она рабочая, и воспроизводит проблему)

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import os
import tensorflow as tf

def load_data(name):
    train_dataset = h5py.File('datasets/' + name + '.h5', "r")
    train_x = np.array(train_dataset["train_x"][:])
    train_y = np.array(train_dataset["train_y"][:])
    train_y = train_y.reshape((1, train_y.shape[0]))
    return train_x,train_y

def Normalize(train_x):
    max = 0
    for i in train_x:
        for j in i:
            if j > max:
                max = j
    train_x = train_x / max
    return train_x

train_x,train_y = load_data('train_data')
train_x = Normalize(train_x)
train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0],-1)
train_y = train_y.T

seed = 13
l2_k = 0.1
dropout_k = 0.3

np.random.seed(seed)
random.seed(seed)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
tf.random.set_seed(seed)

input = keras.layers.Input(shape = train_x.shape[1])

layer1 = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_k,seed=seed)(keras.layers.Dense(1300,activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1), kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(seed=seed))(input))
layer2 = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_k,seed=seed)(keras.layers.Dense(700,activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1), kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(seed=seed))(layer1))
layer3 = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_k,seed=seed)(keras.layers.Dense(300,activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1), kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(seed=seed))(layer2))
layer4 = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_k,seed=seed)(keras.layers.Dense(70,activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1), kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(seed=seed))(layer3))

output =  keras.layers.Dropout(0,seed=seed)(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(seed=seed))(layer4))

model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01), metrics=[keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=30,validation_split = 0.2, batch_size=256)

plt.plot(hist.history['binary_accuracy'], label = 'train accuracy')
plt.plot(hist.history['val_binary_accuracy'], label = 'test accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: добавил полный фрагмент кода который воспроизводит проблему, а также ссылку на файл с тренировочными данными

Comment: а что представляет из себя обучающая выборка? что это за данные? Мне кажется у вас слишком маленькая обучающая выборка - всего 3042 экземпляра при 8000 признаков.

Comment: Я пробовал логистическую регрессию на эти данные натравить, что-то она нифига не сходится. И если кросс-валидацию делать, то тоже не учится ничему толком. Я делаю вывод, что данные по сути близки к случайным и никакая нейросеть там не поможет, сигнала в данных просто нет. Хотя можно ещё попробовать фичи поотбирать, но что-то я сомневаюсь.

Comment: С деревьями, кстати, чуть лучше - удаётся добиться точности минимум 0.65 на 5 фолдах. Короче, данные у вас не линейные, нужно какие-то деревья применять. А как деревья изображать нейросетями я не очень в курсе.

Comment: каждаю запись представляет из себя 200 слепков состояний "обьекта" после которых происходит 1 из 2 действий, тобишь как бы предшественики действия, что конкретно за данные, и что подразумевается под "обьектом"  к сожалению сказать не могу

Comment: Да вот знать бы как между собой фичи связаны (во времени или пространстве), может было бы возможно что-то из них ещё вытянуть. А как есть сейчас сигнал очень слабый выходит. И нелинейный. Логарифмирование несколько улучшает графики данных, но ситуацию с обучением всё-равно не спасает в итоге. У тех же деревьев важность фич получается равномерно разбросана по столбцам. Хотя некоторые фичи чуть важнее и идут они несколько подряд.

Comment: связаны по времени

Comment: Ага, ну я бы попробовал сделать новые фичи, полученные вычитанием соседних колонок и соседних сэмплов, может из этого выйдет что-то интересное. Может быть даже не только со сдвигом 1, а с несколькими разными сдвигами попробовать сделать. Но времени нет попробовать. Ещё можно попробовать какую-нибудь кластеризацию, но не факт, что взлетит.

Comment: Так то обычно фичи пробуют перемножать, но если у вас 8000 фич, это просто нереально. Если только опять же соседние пробовать перемножать, а не все подряд. Если бы фич было сильно меньше, деревянные методы справились бы и без взаимодействия фич, но на 8000 фич никаких деревьев физически не хватит ухватить взаимодействия, нужно им помогать.

Comment: В общем, я попробовал всякое, сдвиги ничего не дали. И собственно нейросеть не хочет учиться, не знаю, что с ней делать. Но если что связка `PCA` + `RF` работает неплохо, скор где-то 0.65 хотя бы получается, хотя это всё-равно мало, но без `PCA` от 0.5 вообще сложно оторваться даже с `RF`.